# How to keeping my AICar on track?

Tags: unity, ai

so today I made an arcade race game but stuck on make AICar that keep on track when play,
what I've made is the AICar sometimes cutting the track or like making a shortcut to the next checkpoint and I won't that happen

[image]

**What I've done**

- Make more checkpoints so the car going more smoothly

this my whole AICar script:

```
private void Start()
    {
        theRB.transform.parent = null;

        dragOnGround = theRB.drag;

        if (isAI)
        {
            targetPoint = RaceManager.Instance.allCheckpoints[this.currentTarget].transform.position;
            //RandomiseAITarget();
            aiSpeedMod = Random.Range(.8f, 1.1f);
        }

        UIManager.Instance.LapCounterText.text = currentLap + "/" + RaceManager.Instance.TotalLap.ToString();
    }

 private void Update()
    {
        lapTime += Time.deltaTime;

            targetPoint.y = transform.position.y;

            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPoint) <= aiReachPointRange)
            {
                SetNextTarget();
            }

            Vector3 targetDir = (targetPoint - transform.position);
            float angle = Vector3.Angle(targetDir, transform.forward);

            Vector3 localPos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(targetPoint);
            if (localPos.x < 0)
            {
                angle = -angle;
            }

            //AI turning
            turnInput = Mathf.Clamp(angle / aiMaxTurn, -1f, 1f);

            if (Mathf.Abs(angle) < aiMaxTurn)
            {
                aiSpeedInput = Mathf.MoveTowards(aiSpeedInput, 1f, aiAccelerateSpeed);
            }
            else
            {
                aiSpeedInput = Mathf.MoveTowards(aiSpeedInput, aiTurnSpeed, aiAccelerateSpeed);
            }

            speedInput = aiSpeedInput * fowardAcceleration * aiSpeedMod;
    }

 public void SetNextTarget()
    {
        this.currentTarget++;

        if (this.currentTarget >= RaceManager.Instance.allCheckpoints.Length)
        {
            this.currentTarget = 0;
        }

        targetPoint = RaceManager.Instance.allCheckpoints[this.currentTarget].transform.position;
        //RandomiseAITarget();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to add more waypoints around the turns. Think of it this way; every time a driver would need to turn the wheel, there should be a waypoint. However, collisions might still push the cars of the track slightly.

Another way would be to use a NavMesh.

You can set the grass to not have the Navigation Static flag, so the NavMesh would not include it. Then adding a NavMeshAgent component on your cars and using the navMeshAgent.SetDestination(point) would make sure the cars stay in the track.

Look here: [Building a NavMesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html)

The AICar script would look something like this:

```
NavMeshAgent myAgent;

void Update()
{
    if (!myAgent.hasPath)
    {
        SetNextTarget();
    }
}
    
void SetNextTarget()
{
    this.currentTarget++;

        if (this.currentTarget >= RaceManager.Instance.allCheckpoints.Length)
        {
            this.currentTarget = 0;
        }
        
        myAgent.SetDestination(RaceManager.Instance.allCheckpoints[this.currentTarget].transform.position);
}
```

One thing to note, is that NavMeshAgents have collision avoidance which means they won't collide with each other. You CAN have the player object collide with them, and handle forces manually in `OnCollisionEnter()` (Look [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-MixingComponents.html)), but it might be a lot easier adding the `NavMeshObstacle` component on the player object. This would make the Agents avoid colliding with the player object as well.